# How to verify the account name exists or not in SQLite

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have a box to write my account name  I have a button & I want when I write inside the box
Press the button
Checks whether the account name is present or not in sqlite
I want to check it before sending it to the database whether the account exists or not
This is my code I want to help

class

```
    package com.example.java.beta;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;



public class accounts extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public accounts(Context context)
    {
        super(context, "accounts.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table users(username varchar(30),password varchar(30))");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

file java

```
package com.example.java.beta;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class register extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText ed_username;
    TextView btn_register;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);


        ed_username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_username);
        btn_register = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.btn_register);


        Typeface unfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font_welcome.woff");
        ed_username.setTypeface(unfont);
        btn_register.setTypeface(unfont);







    }


    public void reg(View view) {


                accounts call = new accounts(register.this);
                SQLiteDatabase create = call.getWritableDatabase();
                create.execSQL("insert into users values(?,?)",
                        new String [] {ed_username.getText().toString(),ed_password.getText().toString()});

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to check if a record exists in database :

```
accounts call = new accounts(register.this);
SQLiteDatabase create = call.getWritableDatabase();
String Query = "Select * from " + users + " where " + username + " = " + ed_username.getText();
Cursor cursor = create.rawQuery(Query, null);
    if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
        create.execSQL("insert into users values(?,?)",
                    new String [] {ed_username.getText().toString(),ed_password.getText().toString()});
    }
cursor.close();
```

Comment: look this when press to button stoped applaction why?

Comment: Try and place it in between ` ` like `code`. Also no space between the tags and character

Comment: this query can in some cases be sped up by adding `LIMIT 1`. There's no point to search for more rows if we know there's at least one. That's sufficient to answer OP's question